# How to show an image fit to mobile screen?

Tags: css, html

I have tried to implement a responsive web page to view an image. In order to do that, I use HTML5. Below is an example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .center{margin: 0px auto; display: block;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <picture>
        <source media="print" srcset="https://www.mywebsiteurl/point_th@monochrome">
        <source media="(max-width: 480px)"
                srcset="https://www.mywebsiteurl/point_th@1x">
        <source media="(max-width: 640px)"
                srcset="https://www.mywebsiteurl/point_th@2x">
        <source media="(max-width: 1024px)"
                srcset="https://www.mywebsiteurl/point_th@4x">
        <img src="https://www.mywebsiteurl/point_th@4x" class="center">
    </picture>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the view of website from my cellphone (Samsung Galaxy S6 Edger):

[image: View from my cellphone]

From the view of my cellphone, I see there is a white space around my picture. So how can I make it fit to the screen without white space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The must be the problem of body default spacing

body has a default spacing in every html page we need to set it to 0

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Good! But it still have space from left and right side of the image.

Comment: would you be able to create a fiddle...there must be some other problem

Comment: Hi Gaurav Aggarwal, I think your answer is correct. There is a problem with the picture width. I will fix this later. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

This will set the margin and padding of all elements to `0` but be sure this is the first thing in your CSS file.

You can also try

```
picture {
 height: 100vh; // vh is viewport height
 width: 100vw; // vw is viewport width
}
```

Comment: but you cant be sure that there is only a picture on page

Comment: Actually there is only one picture. But picture { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; } has no effect on the page, at lease I have tested on my cell phone.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal that's when you target that specific image using a class or something like `.containingDiv > picture`.

@Trind07 that means something is adding margins for some reason which is odd if you reset the margins using my first code snippet.

Comment: ya i can undestand that here only there is one picture on the page but i am talking about standard that we can't just write css like this...read w3 css standards

Comment: I was just going by what's posted in this particular example since there are no `class` or `id` to work with. Honestly I'm surprised an image is being used for that bit of text.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers will have default body margin. u can remove it by:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same answer as others have however i have one suggestion to add

Try using [reset css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). Using any of these CSS files helps a lot especially in such case.
Codes mentioned in answer like

```
*{
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
 }
```

are already there in these files. It has a lot more content that removes default styling of browsers and gives you a neat and clean way to define your own CSS.